# Exporting internal Runnable Classes into jar (Clips)

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I am having trouble with exporting a project I am working on that is calling internal classes that thread events by implementing runnable. It will work correctly in eclipse, but when exported, it will fail to initiate the internal classes. This only occurs with classes implementing runnable.

This only occurs in the exported jar format, but will work perfectly well within eclipse.

I'm calling the thread with:

```
new Thread(new SomeRunnable()).start();
```

Where SomeRunnable is

```
public class SomeRunnable implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {
    //Create a clip
    try {
        Clip clip;
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
        clip.open(audioIn);
        clip.loop(reps);
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("Successful.");
}
```

When exported into runnable jar format, the program will start up correctly and display the GUI, but when it is told to run the thread SomeRunnable, it will do nothing, and not even enter the try catch statement, as it does not play a clip, nor does it exit the program. This shows that the jar isn't recognizing the class files and won't call them from the main method.

What would cause the jar to work differently than how eclipse handles the code?

Comment: This just shouldn't happen. Maybe your export misses something. You can try remote debugging: http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t53459.html or add some extra log messages. Can you see the inner classes in the exported jar?

Comment: Yes, I took the jar file and and changed it to a zip file to look what was inside, and all the required files were there. I'll try that link, though. Thanks!

Comment: I also have quite a few log messages and have nailed the problem to only be a major issue with classes implementing runnable. The program will recognize any other class that do not implement the feature.

Comment: Try updating your Java... It might work. What version do you have? Also, try compiling the jar yourself with the jar tool in your JDK.

Comment: I couldn't get the compiler to compile any classes at all, as it kept throwing NoClassDefFoundError, but that's another issue entirely. I'm running 1.7.0_09

Comment: After looking a bit more into the exported runnable jar, I found that it had all the files that Eclipse was making use of, so the jar SHOULD have everything it needs. One strange thing I did notice that may or may not be significant is that in my project folder in eclipse, there is a jar (forms-1.3.0.jar) that doesn't export with the program. I manually placed it inside the jar, but it had no effect.

Comment: I did some more research on the subject and discovered that it isn't actually the runnable classes at all, but in fact, the File I/O involved with the jar, although I have not shown the I/O here

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the actual solution was that I was storing my sound files inside the jar, thus my references to the directories were not working, because it had moved the directories. When the sound files were moved to outside of the jar, it worked and read the files and ran the threads.